# a and not(b or c) with Apple Spotlight query

Tags: macos, outlook, spotlight

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html

Apple's dev dox provide info for File Metadata Query Expression Syntax.

The problem I'm having is that I want to do 'A and not(B or C)' but I don't see how to do it. It seems I can only do 'A and ((not B) or (not C))' and that's not what I want. There's a nice truth table generator here that demonstrates the problem: http://turner.faculty.swau.edu/mathematics/materialslibrary/truth/

I'm thinking that it's not possible given what Spotlight supports, per the dox.

**SOLVED**

Some details on the problem I'm trying to solve:
I want to see email to me from outside the company domain AND not webex generated (it is used for meeting updates, etc.) MS Outlook 2011 (Mac) uses OS X Spotlight search engine to filter email with a 'Raw Query'.

The working query (thanks, Renzo) is:

```
com_microsoft_outlook_recpient_email_addresses == "jsmith@example.com" && com_microsoft_outlook_author_email_addresses != "*@example.com" && com_microsoft_outlook_author_email_addresses != "*@webex.com"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the “[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)” the expression `A and not(B or C)` is equal to `A and not(B) and not(C)`, so you can use the `&&` operator and the `!=` operator to express your condition.

Comment: Aha! I should have stayed in school — that did it and it works perfectly!
I used this for the 'Raw Query' in MS Outlook 2011 (Mac) that utilizes the OS X Spotlight search engine. The problem was: I want to see email to me from outside the company domain AND not webex generated (it is used for meeting updates, etc.) The working query is:

com_microsoft_outlook_recpient_email_addresses == "jsmith@example.com" && com_microsoft_outlook_author_email_addresses != "*@example.com" && com_microsoft_outlook_author_email_addresses != "*@webex.com"

Comment: Glad to have helped you.